# How do I create a default file association in Debian with Gnome?

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome3, nautilus, file-descriptors

I'm using Debian Jessie 64-bit with Gnome 3.14.1.

My TIF image files are opening by default in the PDF Viewer, don't ask why. In Nautilus, I right-click on the file, click Open With|Other Application...

[image: Select Application window]

If I right-click "Image Viewer", there is only "Forget association".

Where is the "create default association" button?

EDIT

I've found a ~/.config/mimeapps.list, which contains

```
image/tiff=eog.desktop;
```

It seems that something else is overriding this configuration.

EDIT2

It seems to be /etc/gnome/defaults.list, which contains

```
image/tiff=evince.desktop
```

which is the PDF viewer in question. Removing this line solved this problem. The problem remains, though, if there should be a button "add default" to the image above.

Comment: If you just click "select" does it change the association?

Comment: @fooot Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Debian 10.0.0 Buster + GNOME]

I see the same *deficient* behaviour using 'open with' as you describe.

Select any file having the [MIMETYPE](https://wiki.debian.org/MIME) of interest then right-click -> Properties.

Select the 'Open With' tab.

And there you should see the **Set as default** button.